# On extension of IVP solution

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is:

Let $f$ defined on $C[Q,R^n]$ , Where $Q$ is an open set contained on $R^(n+1)$. Let $U$ be a compact set, V a bounded open set such that $U$ belongs to $V$ and $cl(V)$ belongs to $Q$. Show that for any $(t_0 , x_0)$ belongs to $U$, the IVP $x^\prime$ = $f(t,x)$ , $x(t_0)=x_0$,
has a solution on $[a,b]$ such that $(a, x(a))$  and $(b,x(b))$ are not belong $U$.

I tried to prove that by contradiction and using the extension theorem , but how I can use the $cl(V)$?

Comment: I made a minor edit to your post.  Note, the $\LaTeX$ for $x^\prime$ is either "x^\prime" or "x'", not "x^'",  Cheers!

Comment: No answer guys!!